# Is it possible to run Redux-Form without React-Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

Is there any way to utilise Redux-Form without also bringing in React-Redux library?

I have both React and Redux installed, but I am trying to keep my app as light as possible with as little dependencies as possible.

If there is no way to decouple React-Redux from Redux-Form, is there any other form handling library that you'd recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No.

[react-redux](/questions/tagged/react-redux) is a peer dependency of [redux-form](/questions/tagged/redux-form).

[source](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/master/package.json#L116)